# How to program a virtual sound output device on windows 7+?

Tags: c++, c, audio, wdk, windows-kernel

I want to add a new sound device on windows 7+ so that I can redirect the computer sound on the network (using a protocol of my own or [PulseAudio](http://pulseaudio.org) for example).

Basically, I think I want to write a kernel driver that expose a new sound output device to the OS. If there's a way to write the driver so that I only have to deal with a simple sample buffer input to process it would be great (the simpler the better). I don't care too much about latency, I just want it to be as transparent as possible for the system and the applications running so that everything goes through this virtual device out of the box.

I have some experience in Linux kernel development but I know next to nothing about Windows driver development. I have a genuine Visual Studio 2013 ultimate and I want to target Windows 7 (above would be nice but it *has* to work on W7).

I would like to know which API/framework/system should I use to achieve my goal and possibly link to dev ressources to get me started.

Comment: Ain't that a bit too broad and require a complete tutorial?

Comment: *Any* help is welcome. I'm fine with a roadmap of things to do e.g. "add a new XYZ module, this module would do A for callback X , B for callback Y, look at LINK for more on how to use these."